# Closing the command window with Python after running a Windows command with cmd /k

Tags: python, command-line

In my actual program I want to write in the windows command window. To access the command window I use following command:

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k my text'
```

This works like it should but after this line of code the command window stays in my console until I type 'exit'. After this the code continues. Is there a way of getting out of the command window automatically or do I have to write `exit` every time I use this?

I tried to give a second argument into the command window but this didn't work.

Comment: Is the command window important to have at all? You should generally avoid `os.system` in favor of `subprocess.run` and friends when you can.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `/K`? Does that not specifically ask the `cmd` window to remain after doing `my_text`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to have well understood your question. Here is an example that does not stop your cmd with /c instead of /k.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    os.system('cmd /c echo Hello, World!')
```